# Table row not highlighting with hovered over

Tags: html, css, sass, html-table

For some reason I can't get my entire row to highlight.  If I put the hover on the td tag I can get 1 section of the row to highlight, but I want the entire row of the table to highlight.

I'm using sass and Vue.js -  but the Vue.js shouldn't be interfering

html...

```
                  <table id="tblData">
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                       <th v-for="column in columns">
                         {{ column | uppercase }}
                           </th>
                          </tr>
                       </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   <tr v-for="tableData in tableData">
                      <td>
                          {{ tableData.client }}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          {{ tableData.ad }}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          {{ tableData.rt }}
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
```

the CSS

```
table {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;

}

th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  /*
  &:hover {
    background-color: yellow;   //makes just 1 element highlight on hover
  }
  */
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot change a background colour on a tr, try the following code, this will change the background colour of each of td when a tr is hovered

```
tr:hover td {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `!important` at the end of the attribute like `background-color: yellow !important;` to force the change to happen.

Comment: I should have thought of that!  Unfortunately it didn't work ><